# Return result based on a promise value

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have started using axios, a promise based HTTP client and I haven't figured out how to return a result based on a promise value.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
function isUnique(cif) {
    countClients(cif).then(function(count) {
        return (count == 0);
    });
}

function countClients(cif) {
    return axios.get('/api/clients?cif=' + cif)
        .then(function(response) {
            let clients = response.data;
            return clients.length;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        });
}
```

I expect the isUnique function to return a boolean value based on countClients output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return a synchronous value based on asynchronous calculations. Javascript provides no way for that intentionally. What you can do is to return a `Promise<boolean>`:

```
function isUnique(cif) {
    return countClients(cif).then(function(count) {
        return (count == 0);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

So you need to supply this function to a third party library, and it only works with functions of type `(x:T) => boolean`, but not `(x:T) => Promise<boolean>`. Unfortunately you still cannot "wait for" a promise, this is not how the JavaScript event loop works.

### The right solution

Use a validation library that supports async validation functions.

### The workaround

I don't recommend this, but you could cache all the values you might use prior to action.

So for example, lets say this is how you would call the third party:

```
function isUnique(cif) {
    return true; // Dummy mock
}
var result = ThirdParty.doValidation(isUnique);
console.log(result);
```

Instead, you can write something like this:

```
function isUnique(cif) {
    return countClients(cif).then(function(count) {
        return (count == 0);
    });
}
function getRelevantCifs() {
    return axios.get("/api/all-client-cifs");
}

var isUniqueCache = new Map();
function isUniqueCached(cif) {
    return isUniqueCache.get(cif);
}
function buildCache() {
    return getRelevantCifs().then(cifs => {
        return Promise.all(cifs.map(cif => {
            return isUnique(cif).then(isUniqueResult => {
                isUniqueCache.set(cif, isUniqueResult);
            });
        }));
    });
}
buildCache().then(() => {
    var result = ThirdParty.doValidation(isUniqueCached);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I didn't mention that the isUnique function is used by a validation library and it has to return a `boolean` not a `Promise<boolean>`.

Comment: @FlorinFrătică Unfortunately you still cannot do that. See my updated answer for a workaround. Which validation library are we talking about btw?

Comment: I am using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin. It came out of the box with a template bought from Envato and it is expanded so it can be used only by writing HTML code so I think I would rather use another library for AJAX calls. [Request](https://github.com/request/request) seems like a good alternative.

Comment: Why will be using Request any better? You will face the very same issue. You cannot escape the asynchronous nature of ajax calls. You have to learn how to handle it.